# swift scrollToRow or setContentOffset doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableview. When I pull up to **load more data**, as long as the scroll bar **is scrolling**, the method of scrollToTop will stop the tableview from scrolling instead of scrolling to the top, until the scrolling stops.

All other situations can works good.

How to solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

**scrollToTop funcs**

```swift
func scrollToTop1(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: animated)
}

func scrollToTop2(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
}
```

**Tried the following methods:**

1. reloadData() before scrollToTop

*No effect*

---

2. Async delay scrollToTop

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
    scrollToTop()
}
```

*No effect*

---

3.Use beginUpdates() and endUpdates()

```swift
beginUpdates()
scrollToTop()
beginUpdates()
```

*Can roll to the top, but there will be strange flicker*

---

4. Remove scroll animation

```swift
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)
```

*Can roll to the top, but no animated*

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved. Strictly speaking, my code is not rigorous. I wrote a method to call api to get data. Both refresh and pull-up load will access the same method.

For convenience, the method **UIRefreshControl.endRefreshing** will be executed regardless of the pull-up load or pull-down refresh, which leads to this strange problem.

The record is as above, I hope it can help people who also encounter this weird problem